# How to compile a c code on windows command prompt by using php

Tags: php, c, windows

Using passthru function in PHP I can run an exe e.g hello.exe and get its result but unable to compile e.g hello.c using command tcc hello.c on windows command prompt through php script.

So question is how to run commad tcc hello.c on windows command prompt using php script. php script & cmd.exe are on the came machine.

OS windows XP.

code that i want to compile is hello.c is given below.

php script that is executing hello.exe is also given below.

code from hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
      {

    printf("hello");

      }
```

php code that is succefully accesing and displaying hello.exe

```
enter code here
<?php
echo "Remote compilation:";
$path = escapeshellcmd('C:\\TC\\BIN\\HELLO.exe');
passthru( $path, $return_var);
?>
```

please guide
regards

Comment: Why on earth would you want this? I feel a *lot* of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to give the full path of `tcc`: `escapeshellcmd("C:\\path\\to\\tcc C:\\path\\to\\hello.c");`

Comment: @Bart Friederichs, you are right about security but security can be incorporated in next step. First thing is how to give commands to cmd through php script. Purpose is to be able to remotely compile your c code through a web interface. btw please if you have a more secure way to achieve this then do share that too.

Comment: no, in cases like this, security should be **built in from the start**. It is not something you can "bolt on" later.

Comment: your full path comment worked i used with shell_exec, but it required to set/change permissions for tcc and cmd (at least i did for both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHP documentation:

> The passthru() function is similar to the exec() function in that it
>   executes a command. This function should be used in place of exec() or
>   system() when the output from the Unix command is binary data which
>   needs to be passed directly back to the browser.

But here you are not expecting binary data to be generated from `tcc` and passed to the browser.  A more appropriate function to use would be `shell_exec()`.  E.g.:

```
<?php
echo "Remote compilation:";
$command = escapeshellcmd('YOUR TCC COMPILE COMMAND HERE');
shell_exec($command);
?>
```

Comment: Used following code and it worked, but before that i had to set my cmd & tcc permission using cacls                                 <?php
echo "Remote compilation:";
echo 'Script is executed by: ' . get_current_user() . getmygid();
$command = escapeshellcmd('C:\\TC\\BIN\\tcc C:\\TC\\BIN\\HELLO.C');
$output=shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>